# Couldn't find or load main class in JavaFx sample

Tags: java, class, javafx

I tried to run such sample code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        Label l = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(l), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

I successfully compiled it with `javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.controls HelloFX.java`, where PATH_TO_FX is the path to Open JavaFX 11.

Then tried to run it:

```
$ java HelloFX
Error: Could not find or load main class HelloFX
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application
```

Comment: It seems to me that JRE cannot find the FX classes because your runtime PATH_TO_FX  is probably incorrect or missing

Comment: you need runtime args as well as compile time args .. please follow the instructions from a reasonable tutorial (f.i. at openjfx/io) _exactly_

Comment: You need `--module-path ...` and `--add-modules ...` at run-time as well.

Comment: @kleopatra indeed, thank you.

Comment: @Slaw indeed, thanks.